# std::ranges::lower_bound requirements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I'm trying to modernize a C++ code-base and encountered some issues with `std::ranges`, `std::ranges::lower_bound` in particular when searching for an item within the range using a predicate.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using T = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Pred
{
   auto operator()(const T& lhs, int rhs) const
   {
      return lhs.first < rhs;
   }
};

auto using_std(const std::vector<T>& vec, int i)
{
   const auto iter = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), i, Pred{});
   return iter == vec.end();
}

struct RangesPred : Pred
{
   using Pred::operator();

   auto operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
   {
      return lhs.first < rhs.first;
   }
   auto operator()(int lhs, const T& rhs) const
   {
      return lhs < rhs.first;
   }
   auto operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const
   {
      return lhs < rhs;
   }
};

auto using_ranges(const std::vector<T>& vec, int i)
{
   const auto iter = std::ranges::lower_bound(vec, i, RangesPred{});
   return iter == vec.end();
}
```

I've tested this with gcc 13.2 and msvc 19.37, clang 17.0.1 and they all require the `operator()` overloads in RangesPred. None of them are actually calling them, but it seems this is due to the concept requirements for `std::ranges::lower_bound`.

Is this a known "bug"? Is there a neater way of doing this?